# How to estimate the bound on a random variable with semi-infinite distribution?

Tags: distributions, fitting, bounds

Given samples of a random variable which appears to have a continuous unimodal probability density function that is zero on one side of a bound, what statistical methods are there for estimating that value? In this context the shape of the distribution is unknown and less important than the value that bounds the distribution.

Comment: I would think that assumptions about the shape are necessary to develop any reasonable answer.  After all, it takes a huge sample to have any hope of distinguishing a uniform$[0,1]$ variable from a mixture of a uniform$[0,1]$ and uniform$[0,10^{100}]$ variable with weights $1-10^{-9}$ and $10^{-9}$, respectively.

Comment: If the objective was to find the lower bound of a variable with one of the two distributions you describe, there would be no need to distinguish them because both distribution have a lower bound of zero. I should have been clearer that the general class of shape of the distribution is apparent, but my point is that it's not important to infer with as much confidence where the distribution's mode is or the characteristics of its tail, so long as the value of the bound is clearer.

Comment: Those remarks don't seem to address the difficulty.  If the "general shape" is apparent, then you might try to exploit that.  Otherwise, you cannot rule out the possibility of a long extended tail (in either direction) and you have no basis to estimate its terminus.

Comment: I mean to explicitly rule out the possibility of a tail on the bounded side of the distribution. I think from the data it would be satisfactory to assume that the probability density function has its maximum gradient at the bound.

Comment: That is potentially helpful assumption.  You should explicitly include it in the text of your question.  However, it's still not enough: a tiny alteration of the example I gave will put the maximum gradient right at $10^{100}$.  The problem is that control over the maximum absolute derivative of the density doesn't give any practical constraint on the distribution.